# php form: cannot update the database, query with multiple join

Tags: php, mysql, forms, join, mysqli

EDIT#2: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edf825/4/0)

EDIT#1: i see everything in fields now, but cannot update. all queries by themselves work.

I have a page that must show information from database for update. The query has multiple join. The query itself works.

I do not get error message(and the usual methods in order to get a hidden or disabled error message do not work), so I do not know what is wrong, but the form is blank and doesn't edit anything(sometimes blank forms edit information to empty fields).

I've had similar issues many times (and constantly google everything) and errors  differ, but none of the previous things I had to deal with seem to be the reason.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

include "../config.php";

isset($_GET['idorg']) ? $idorg=$_GET['idorg'] : $idorg='';
isset($_GET['nameorg']) ? $nameorg=$_GET['nameorg'] : $nameorg='';
isset($_GET['typeorg']) ? $typeorg=$_GET['typeorg'] : $typeorg='';
isset($_GET['emailorg']) ? $emailorg=$_GET['emailorg'] : $emailorg='';
isset($_GET['cperorg']) ? $cperorg=$_GET['cperorg'] : $cperorg='';
isset($_GET['conorg']) ? $conorg=$_GET['conorg'] : $conorg='';
isset($_GET['comorg']) ? $comorg=$_GET['comorg'] : $comorg='';
isset($_GET['idci']) ? $idci=$_GET['idci'] : $idci='';
isset($_GET['nameci']) ? $nameci=$_GET['nameci'] : $nameci='';
isset($_GET['nameco']) ? $nameco=$_GET['nameco'] : $nameco='';
isset($_GET['idco']) ? $idco=$_GET['idco'] : $idco='';
isset($_GET['submit']) ? $submit=true : $submit=false;


if(!$submit)
{

$query = "select dISTINCT   org.idorg, org.nameorg, org.typeorg, org.emailorg,  org.cperorg, org.conorg, org.comorg, idci, country.nameco, city.nameci, idco
from org 
join city on city.idci=org.city_idci 
JOIN country on country.idco=org.city_country_idco
where idorg=?
group by idorg

";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query))
{

$stmt-> bind_param("i", $idorg);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($idorg, $nameorg, $typeorg, $emailorg, $cperorg, $conorg, $comorg, $idci,$nameci,  $nameco, $idco);
$stmt->fetch();

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

    echo'
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>h1{color:red;}label{color:darkred;}</style>
<title>Edit user</title>
<meta charset=”UTF-8”>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Edit organisation:</h1>
<form action="" method="GET">
<label>ID </label><input readonly name="idorg" value="'.$idorg.'"><br>
<label>Name org </label><input type="text" name="nameorg" value="'.$nameorg.'"><br>
<label>Type </label><input type="text" name="typeorg" value="'.$typeorg.'"><br>
<label>e-mail </label><input type="text" name="emailorg" value="'.$emailorg.'"><br>
<label>contact person </label><input type="text" name="cperorg" value="'.$cperorg.'"><br>
<label>contact</label><input type="text" name="conorg" value="'.$conorg.'"><br>
<label>comment </label><input type="text" name="comorg" value="'.$comorg.'"><br>
<label>cityID </label><input readonly name="idci" value="'.$idci.'"><br>
<label>city </label><input type="text" name="nameci" value="'.$nameci.'"><br>
<label>country </label><input type="text" name="nameco" value="'.$nameco.'"><br>
<label>countryID </label><input readonly name="idci" value="'.$idco.'"><br>
<input type="reset" value="clear">
<input type="submit" value="add" name="submit"><br>
</form>
</body>

</html>
';
}
}else{
$query1 = "UPDATE org
join city on city.idci=org.city_idci 
JOIN country on country.idco=org.city_country_idco
SET nameorg=?, typeorg=?, nameco=?, nameci=? emailorg=?, cperorg=?, conorg=?, comorg=?, idci=?, idco=?  WHERE idorg=?";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query1))
{

$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssiii', $nameorg, $typeorg,$nameco, $nameci,  $emailorg, $cperorg, $conorg, $comorg, $idci, $idco, $idorg);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
header('Location: view.php');
//echo "<a href='view.php'>back</a>";
}

?>
```

Here  is [EER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCXi4.png) of database.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you `echo` created query for Update at last ?

Comment: Close your form tag please...

Comment: I edited code a bit, and now I can see some fields, but in a field "country" i see city(nameci).
UPDATE query works by itself.

Comment: echo your form contents and $submit content

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what you mean. do you want to see screenshots of what is shown in the form or what?

Comment: Can you show us an example of a query out there somewhere that has both a GROUP BY clause and a DISTINCT modifier? Generally, a GROUP BY clause has no place in a query devoid of aggregating functions (with one irritating caveat)

Comment: ahah, i got it, you are right, this is pointless to use together. i deleted that part, but that didn\t seem to have effect whatsoever.

i made sqlfiddle(not sure how long it will be active, the last i made gone missing):
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edf825/4/0

Answer (score -2):

why you use 

**if(!$submit) ???**

may be it'll be 

**if($submit)**

Comment: If `$submit` is false(Means not to update because form is not filled up) then he will `select` data to display else he will `update`.