# Form: INSERT into database, not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert, sql-update

I cannot seem to make this code work. *It is also a base for my other page(update) that doesn't [want to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303030/php-form-cannot-update-the-database-query-with-multiple-join) update.*

The code is supposed to add information into the database.

The query works by itself. I thought that maybe query is too complex(because **pro** 
has fields that are connected to different tables: **fundpro**, **city**, **typepro** and **city** is connected to **country**), but since it works by itself I guess there is a way to make it work in PHP and I'm just doing it wrong.

In update page(link above to question and the code) form shows correct fields, so I assume there are no major mistakes in both pages, the problem is in the "delivery" of the information to the database or something.

I really need the insert-data page, it is practically the only page i really need in the end, and I cannot make it work to my **org** and **pro** tables, while my **country** tables has workable add and edit pages that is quite similar.

I ran out of ideas what might be the reason and I do not know how to make it work for me. Maybe someone sees the problem or knows an alternative approach?

**tl;dr** data doesn't get INSERTed into the database from the fields. query is coccer by itself,  based on update.php file, form returns the information correctly.

Here are [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edf825/4/0) and [EER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCXi4.png).

```
    <?php 
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');


    isset($_GET['submit'])?$submit=true:$submit=false;

    if(!$submit){
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>h1{color:red;}label{color:darkred;}</style>
    <title>Add project</title>
    <meta charset=”UTF-8”>      

    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Add project:</h1>
    <form name="f1" action="" method="GET" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)">


<label>IDpro </label><input type="text" name="idpro"><br>
<label>numpro</label><input type="text" name="numpro" ><br>
<label>namepro </label><input type="text" name="namepro" ><br>
<label>datef </label><input type="text" name="datef" ><br>
<label>datet </label><input type="text" name="datet" ><br>
<label>descr </label><input type="text" name="descr" ><br>
<label>typepro </label><input type="text" name="typepro" ><br>
<label>fundpro </label><input type="text" name="fundpro" ><br>
<label>IDci </label><input type="text" name="idpro" ><br>


    <input type="reset" value="clear">
    <input type="submit" value="add" name="submit"><br>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    }else{
        include "../config.php";
    isset($_GET['idpro']) ? $idpro=$_GET['idpro'] : $idpro='';
    isset($_GET['numpro']) ? $numpro=$_GET['numpro'] : $numpro='';
    isset($_GET['namepro']) ? $namepro=$_GET['namepro'] : $namepro='';
    isset($_GET['datef']) ? $datef=$_GET['datef'] : $datef='';
    isset($_GET['datet']) ? $datet=$_GET['datet'] : $datet='';
    isset($_GET['descr']) ? $descr=$_GET['descr'] : $descr='';
    isset($_GET['typepro']) ? $typepro=$_GET['typepro'] : $typepro='';
    isset($_GET['fundpro']) ? $fundpro=$_GET['fundpro'] : $fundpro='';
    isset($_GET['idci']) ? $idci=$_GET['idci'] : $idci='';

        $sql="INSERT INTO pro(idpro, numpro, namepro, datef, datet, descr,typepro_idtypepro, fundpro_idfundpro, city_idci) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bind_param('ssddsiiii', $numpro, $namepro, $datef, $datet,$descr, $typepro_idtypepro, $fundpro_idfundpro, $city_idci, $idpro);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();

        $mysqli->close();

        header("Location: view.php");
        //}
    }
    ?>
```

**UPDATE: simpler code, same pattern:**

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');


isset($_GET['submit'])?$submit=true:$submit=false;

if(!$submit){
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>h1{color:red;}label{color:darkred;}</style>
<title>Add city</title>
<meta charset=”UTF-8”>      

</head>

<body>

<h1>Add city:</h1>
<form name="f1" action="" method="GET" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)" >
<label>city id </label><input type="text" name="idci"><br>
<label>city </label><input type="text" name="nameci"><br>

<label>country id </label><input type="text" name="country_idco"><br>
<input type="reset" value="clear">
<input type="submit" value="add" name="submit"><br>


</body>
</html>
<?php
}else{
    include "../config.php";
    isset($_GET['idci'])?$idci=$_GET['idci']:$idci='';
    isset($_GET['nameci'])?$nameci=$_GET['nameci']:$nameci='';
//  isset($_GET['nameco'])?$nameco=$_GET['nameco']:$nameco='';
    isset($_GET['idco'])?$idco=$_GET['idco']:$idco='';

    //if(($name!='')&&($nameci!='')&&($nameco!='')){
        //echo "$name $nameci $nameco";


    $sql="INSERT INTO city(idci, nameci,country_idco) VALUES (?,?,?)";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bind_param('isi', $idci, $nameci, $country_idco);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();

    $mysqli->close();

    header("Location: view.php");
    //}
}
```

Comment: hello, could you please post error ? you can use this http://php.net/manual/tr/mysqli.error.php

Comment: You should probably go with the pattern: `$x = isset($y) ? $y : $z` rather than using the ternary to run one of two different assignments.

Comment: shows no error.

Comment: @tadman, I am not sure how to change the code to fit the pattern, but thanks for suggestion, i'll try to understand it. The thing is, the code basically works with simpler queries, so I suppose it should work with this one too?

Comment: does it give you any errors ?

Comment: For one thing, these `<meta charset=”UTF-8”>` contain curly quotes and is breaking our encoding. You need to change all of them to regular quotes `<meta charset="UTF-8">`. Having PHP error reporting on, would have thrown you an error about it.

Comment: Then the order you have columns and values setup, should be throwing you an error. You have `idpro` as the first `INSERT INTO pro(idpro`, but then it's the last one in binds `...$fundpro_idfundpro, $city_idci, $idpro);`

Comment: You're also using JS `onSubmit="return validateForm(this)"` but didn't include that code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<label>IDpro </label><input type="text" name="idpro"><br>
<label>numpro</label><input type="text" name="numpro" ><br>
<label>namepro </label><input type="text" name="namepro" ><br>
<label>datef </label><input type="text" name="idpro" ><br>
<label>datet </label><input type="text" name="idpro" ><br>
<label>descr </label><input type="text" name="descr" ><br>
<label>typepro </label><input type="text" name="numpro" ><br>
<label>fundpro </label><input type="text" name="numpro" ><br>
<label>IDci </label><input type="text" name="idpro" ><br>
```

You have set the name of multiple input fields to same value.
Like:

```
<label>typepro </label><input type="text" name="numpro" ><br>
<label>fundpro </label><input type="text" name="numpro" ><br>
```

Your Query:

```
  $sql="INSERT INTO pro(idpro, numpro, namepro, datef, datet, descr,typepro_idtypepro, fundpro_idfundpro, city_idci) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

You see there the order -  (idpro, numpro, namepro, datef, datet, descr,typepro_idtypepro, fundpro_idfundpro, city_idci); Your database expects the arguments you provide to match them. So, the first argument will be mapped onto idpro. If you send idpro as the last argument, it will be mapped to city_idci causing datatype mismatch error.

Correct your order and get your basics right.

Comment: What exactly is the issue then?

Comment: i have no idea  thats why I've asked the question

Comment: By issue I meant the problem you're facing. And update the question with edited code and specifying what exactly your "problem" is

Comment: "The code is supposed to add information into the database. the problem is in the "delivery" of the information to the database or something." i thought it was clear

Comment: $idpro is 9th. it is put in the back instead of the beginning because that's how we were taught to write code. i tried to put it first but nothing changed. i counted everything at least 20 times considering how long i try to fix it :D

Comment: edited, placing of $idpro does nothing.
for comaring, i added simplier code(just different table used) that also is not working. maybe it is easier to spot what's wrong that way.

Comment: $stmt->bind_param('isi', $idci, $nameci, $country_idco); There's no variable "$country_idco" defined.

Comment: You can never get your code working if you continue to be ignorant.

Comment: I tried to redo the whole thing, and yeah, I finally got what you meant, but it still didn't make much difference.
Your last comment is quite upsetting, but there is truth in it, since I cannot make this code work, no matter what. And I didn't want to update 10 more times of things i changed but didn't affected anything, including writing this code from beginning(which works until I make query more complex).
In the end I found a simpler way out, which is using a different method entirely.

Comment: thanks for help anyway, I'll keep being ignorant due to lack of abilities and time, I spent more than I had and planned more than I could.
I was lucky to get help elsewhere and now I have what I needed, but not with my own abilities, sadly. 
Hope Stackoverflow will have less people like me, because I do get how frustrating it must be to deal with newbies/hobbyists like me(who in the end lack enthusiasm and commitment to finish a thing), my deepest apologies.

Answer (score -1):

You are only allowing for 9 parameters in your insert statement but are passing through 10 in your `bind_param` method.

Comment: @Evan yes, but you were passing through 10